# Selenium doesnt implement click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to implement a click on an element in a table. At the moment im searching the table for a specific string. If the string matches i return the element to its calling method and try to implement the click but the calling method never clicks the element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Check table method.

```
public static WebElement chk_TableContentsByXpath(String searchString, String elements){
    WebElement element = null;
        try{
            // Grab the table
            WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elements));

            // Now get all the TR elements from the table
            List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            // And iterate over them, getting the cells
            for (WebElement row : allRows) {
                List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
             for (WebElement cell : cells) {
                // System.out.println(cell.getText());
                    if(cell.getText().equals(searchString)){
                        element = cell;
                        return element;
                    }   
             }
            }
     }catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method GetTableContents | Exception occured while search table : "+e.getMessage());
                throw (e);
            }
    return element;
        }
```

Calling method

```
package appModules;

import pageObjects.MC_Page_links;
import pageObjects.MC_ProductTypes_Page;
import pageObjects.TopNav_links;
import utility.Constant;
import utility.Utils;

public class MC_MaterialProductType_UpdateProductType_Action {

    public static void Execute(int iTestCaseRow) throws Exception{ 

        Utils.waitForElement(TopNav_links.lnk_MasterControl());

        TopNav_links.lnk_MasterControl().click();

        MC_Page_links.lnk_ProductTypes();

        Utils.chk_TableContentsByXpath(Constant.MC_ProductTypeName,Constant.MC_ProductTypesTable).click();//this line doesnt implement the click

        MC_ProductTypes_Page.inpt_UpdateProductName().sendKeys(Constant.MC_ProductTypeNameUpdate);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific string, you can use xpath:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elements));

table.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[text() = '" + searchString + "']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try either of the process below:**

**1-** Try replacing the code :

`List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));`

with

`List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("//td"));`

**2-** Also, you can directly return the element, from the method **chk_TableContentsByXpath** using the code below:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elements));

element = table.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),searchString)]"));
```